# material ui - Drawer is semi transparent in dark mode - mui5

Tags: material-ui

Starting mui5, I noticed that the drawer in dark mode has become semi transparent. How to change the opacity of the drawer (not the backdrop).

[image]

```
  <SwipeableDrawer
    open={props.drawerOpened}
    onClose={props.toggleDrawer(false)}
    onOpen={props.toggleDrawer(true)}
    PaperProps={{
      sx: {
        opacity: 1,
      }
    }}
  >
```

The `opacity: 1` above did not work.